# Using node.js modules/code from the JavaScript console of geth

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

I have a JS filter which checks for the ether transferred in a recent transaction. I have loaded this script from the interactive JS console and it's working fine. Based on the ether in the transaction, I want to run external python scripts. For e.g.(Not actual code):

```
if (ether = 10){
  test1(); 
}
```

And the node.js code for these functions:

```
function test1() {
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    var pc1 = spawn("python",["/path/to/test1.py"]);
}
```

This code is working fine when I execute it separately. But when I include this in the JS snippet and reload it to the console(using `loadScript()`), I get the following error:

> err: cannot find module 'child_process'

**child_process** is a default node.js module. I understand that this is not a problem with the code but with the integration of node.js into geth client. Is this not possible at all or are there any workarounds?

Comment: Related: [Any way to execute a Windows/Linux command from geth](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6652/any-way-to-execute-a-windows-linux-command-from-geth)

Answer (score 2):

In few cases node modules would not work in your browser. But there are modules which you can do read here http://www.richardrodger.com/2013/09/27/how-to-make-simple-node-js-modules-work-in-the-browser/#.V3Vco-t97IU.

In your case, it is not possible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509804/execute-node-js-child-process-in-browser-by-browserify)

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about node.js. Here, Why is web3.js library being compared to a browser?

Comment: @varm a typo fixed it.

Comment: I'm not using any browser here. I was just asking whether default node.js modules like `child_process` will work if I load a script containing these modules to the JavaScript console of geth.

Comment: the Javascript console https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console, and I believe no it won't work.

Comment: Any idea why it won't work?

Comment: Yea, when javascript is written for a browser, stuff like opening child processes and writing to the hard disk are blocked as a security measure. this prevents viruses in your web browser. it's annoying that these node modules can't be integrated for geth though, since geth should not just be for web browsers, although apparently it is written as such

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by starting the console (or attaching to it later) with a 'preload' argument, eg i was able to load the library "ramda" from my local filesystem with:

```
geth --preload=/ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_JS_LIBRARIES/ramda.min.js attach
```

(use "console" instead of "attach" if you don't already have a geth instance running that you want to attach to)