# Execute a contract from bash or inside a python script

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, python

I have a Mist wallet and a contract (with its address) that i execute from mist GUI "manually".
I was wondering how i can execute it from command line (bash not geth) or call that execution from a python script.
If this is possible could you provide a toy example or a roadmap?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can call geth from bash over JSON-RPC interface using `curl` command

Comment: Also python has various libraries available like https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py/ - that I highly recommend

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thanks! do you have any toy example in mind or something to point me in a right direction? Like a blog post for dummies :) Specially with the python library executing a contract.

Comment: Here is some for bash https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide/blob/master/source/contracts-and-transactions/accessing-contracts-and-transactions.rst

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa that is inside the geth console right? do you have anything on a python script?

Comment: `curl` is a UNIX command, for bash. I am sorry, I have only pretty complex Python examples. Populus documentation might have some http://populus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: thanks @MikkoOhtamaa! complex python examples? you make me wonder now! :) if they are open please share the link :)

Comment: Just dig through Populus, Web3, pyget and py-solc Github repositories

Comment: Lots of examples on the site using shell script. Enter "/bin/sh EOF" (without the quotes) in the search box and there are 12 results. Example http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3570/how-do-i-print-my-account-balances-and-thedao-tokens-from-geth and http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7339/how-to-parse-the-ethereum-blockchain-and-save-the-output-to-a-file-geth-console . And http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8339/1268 has a script that `grep`s and `sed`s only the data of interest.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thanks! will do that. Could not find any youtube video (tutorial on this). How will be first brave :)

Comment: @BokkyPooBah thanks! i will look into these links!

Comment: So many good comments. Now someone write an answer please. :-)

Comment: From bash, I do this sometimes: `echo "<insert command here>" | geth attach`. It's super simple, and it returns the result to standard out. I frequently use `curl` as pointed out above as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of this has already been explored in the comments but I'll summarise as an answer!

## Executing/calling from bash

This is explained pretty thoroughly in the [Homestead Guide to Accessing Contracts and Transactions](https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide/blob/master/source/contracts-and-transactions/accessing-contracts-and-transactions.rst).

From the very basics, Ethereum has an RPC (Remote procedure call) interface, as explained excellently by the Wikipedia [RPC page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). Ethereum's RPC interface uses a subset of the JSON-RPC 2.0 spec, with the following caveats:

- Numbers are hex encoded.
- If the RPC method takes a block number, you can submit either an actual number, or one of the following strings: "earliest", "latest", "pending".

### Commands with bash

Using the RPC interface, we can execute commands such as `eth_coinbase`, which returns your ETH address:

```
> curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_coinbase", "id":1}' localhost:8545
```

Which prints:

```
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":["0xeb85a5557e5bdc18ee1934a89d8bb402398ee26a"]}
```

### Interacting with deployed contracts with bash

Functions from pre-deployed contracts are interacted with through their function signature, which is found by taking the first 4 bytes of the output of `sha3('functionName(functionParameterTypes)')`. This can be computed from inside geth with, for example,

```
> web3.sha3("multiply(uint256)").substring(0, 8)
"c6888fa1"
```

A helpful note here is that even if you've used `uint` or `int` within your contract, you'll have to use the real deal like eg `uint256`.

You pad your input (encoded in hex) with zeros, like the following, for an example input of 6:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
```

You do this so the length is a multiple of 32 bytes, but usually I just copy the example and change the end so as not to have to hit the 0 button 8 billion times.

Now quoting straight from [the docs](https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide/blob/master/source/contracts-and-transactions/accessing-contracts-and-transactions.rst), we have:

Combining the function selector and the encoded argument our data will be:

```
0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
```

Lets try it:

```
> curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method": "eth_sendTransaction", "params": [{"from": "0xeb85a5557e5bdc18ee1934a89d8bb402398ee26a", "to": "0x6ff93b4b46b41c0c3c9baee01c255d3b4675963d", "data": "0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006"}], "id": 8}' localhost:8545
{"id":8,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x759cf065cbc22e9d779748dc53763854e5376eea07409e590c990eafc0869d74"}
```

Since we sent a transaction we got the transaction hash returned. You can have way more exciting examples that return results of function calls.

## Calling with Python scripts

I haven't tested a single one of these, but from the comments, links to explore include:

- [Populus](http://populus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)
- [py-solc](https://github.com/pipermerriam/py-solc)
- [web3.py](https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [0xweb](https://github.com/0xweb-org/0xweb) tool to **read** from a contract and **write** (send transactions) to the contract.

```shell
$ npm i 0xweb -g
```

Then you have to install the contract from etherscan, and other evm chains, but the contracts should be validated.

```shell
$ 0xweb install 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48 --name USDC --chain eth 
$ 0xweb contract read USDC balanceOf --account 0x0a59649758aa4d66e25f08dd01271e891fe52199 --chain eth
```

You can list all available methods with the required parameters for the installed contract by name:

```shell
$ 0xweb contract abi USDC --chain eth
```